# How to include GridView and ListView together in one layout

Tags: android, listview, clickable

I am building an app where i have to use both gridview and listview in same activity but the problem is gridview items are clickable but not the listview this is my xml of activity...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:numColumns="3" >

</GridView>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="180dp"
        android:text="Run Background" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="Add To Cart" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Edit Cart" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:background="@layout/editext_background"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Quantity" />

</TableRow>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_slno"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Item Name"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Quantity"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_phone"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Price"
        android:textColor="#000" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_marginRight="105dp"
    android:text="Bill"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/gridView1" >

</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:text="Tender" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
    android:text="Delete" />
```

please help me how to make listview item and row clickable ......

Comment: I removed the reference to 7" tablets in the title, because the size of your screen has nothing to do with your problem. In order to trouble-shoot, you might want to include your activity code (especially your onClick handlers), because I have a list/grid layout in one of my apps, and it works a charm.

Comment: @323go-please give me ur email i will send the activity code

Comment: Sorry, but my email only goes to paying clients. You can post it here, and someone (or me) will likely help you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried android:clickable="true"?

like:

```
<TableRow
android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
android:clickable="true"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginTop="23dp" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine the height of the grid view first. Use this tutorial.
http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/03/combining-gridview-and-listview-in-one.html

Comment: Don't post links. Links might get expired and not workable.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you only need to put 2 RecyclerViews object to your activity/fragment layout. For better scroll later, please wrap theme in a NestedScrollView like this: 
activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#ffffe0"
    tools:context="info.devexchanges.gridlistrecyclerview.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="@string/os"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/grid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/corporation"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Of course, you always need to creating layout for each RecyclerView item. In this every item is a CardView: 
item_list.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

item_grid.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@null" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Now, we must create 2 adapter classes for 2 RecyclerViews based on RecyclerView.Adapter:

ListViewAdapter.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

import info.devexchanges.gridlistrecyclerview.R;
import info.devexchanges.gridlistrecyclerview.RecyclerViewItem;

public class ListViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Activity activity;
    private List<RecyclerViewItem> items;

    public ListViewAdapter(Activity activity, List<RecyclerViewItem> items) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(items.get(position).getDrawableId());
        viewHolder.textView.setText(items.get(position).getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    /**
     * View holder to display each RecylerView item
     */
    protected class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ImageView imageView;
        private TextView textView;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
            textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text);
        }

    }
}
```

GridViewAdapter.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

import info.devexchanges.gridlistrecyclerview.R;
import info.devexchanges.gridlistrecyclerview.RecyclerViewItem;

public class GridViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GridViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<RecyclerViewItem> items;
    private Activity activity;

    public GridViewAdapter(Activity activity, List<RecyclerViewItem> items) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_grid, viewGroup, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(GridViewAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(items.get(position).getDrawableId());
        viewHolder.textView.setText(items.get(position).getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    /**
     * View holder to display each RecylerView item
     */
    protected class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ImageView imageView;
        private TextView textView;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text);
            imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }
    }
}
```

There is no special point in your activity or fragment programmatically code, locating all xml elements from layout file, create LayoutManager for RecyclerViews, initializing adapters and attaching them,...This is full code for my main activity:

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import info.devexchanges.gridlistrecyclerview.adapter.GridViewAdapter;
import info.devexchanges.gridlistrecyclerview.adapter.ListViewAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView listView;
    private RecyclerView gridView;
    private ListViewAdapter listViewAdapter;
    private GridViewAdapter gridViewAdapter;
    private ArrayList<RecyclerViewItem> corporations;
    private ArrayList<RecyclerViewItem> operatingSystems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        gridView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.grid);

        setDummyData();

        listView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        gridView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        //set layout manager and adapter for "ListView"
        LinearLayoutManager horizontalManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        listView.setLayoutManager(horizontalManager);
        listViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, corporations);
        listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);

        //set layout manager and adapter for "GridView"
        GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
        gridView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        gridViewAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, operatingSystems);
        gridView.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);
    }

    private void setDummyData() {
        corporations = new ArrayList<>();
        corporations.add(new RecyclerViewItem(R.drawable.microsoft, "Microsoft"));
        corporations.add(new RecyclerViewItem(R.drawable.apple, "Apple"));
        corporations.add(new RecyclerViewItem(R.drawable.google, "Google"));
        corporations.add(new RecyclerViewItem(R.drawable.oracle, "Oracle"));
        corporations.add(new RecyclerViewItem(R.drawable.yahoo, "Yahoo"));
        corporations.add(new RecyclerViewItem(R.drawable.mozilla, "Mozilla"));

        operatingSystems = new ArrayList<>();
        operatingSystems.add(new RecyclerViewItem(R.drawable.bbos, "BlackBerry OS"));
        operatingSystems.add(new RecyclerViewItem(R.drawable.ios, "iOS"));
        operatingSystems.add(new RecyclerViewItem(R.drawable.tizen, "Tizen"));
        operatingSystems.add(new RecyclerViewItem(R.drawable.android, "Android"));
        operatingSystems.add(new RecyclerViewItem(R.drawable.symbian, "Symbian"));
        operatingSystems.add(new RecyclerViewItem(R.drawable.firefox_os, "Firefox OS"));
        operatingSystems.add(new RecyclerViewItem(R.drawable.wp_os, "Windows Phone OS"));
    }
}
```

And this is the POJO class of this project: 
RecyclerViewItem.java

```
public class RecyclerViewItem {

    private int drawableId;
    private String name;

    public RecyclerViewItem(int drawableId, String name) {
        this.drawableId = drawableId;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getDrawableId() {
        return drawableId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

NOTE: Never forget to put RecyclerView and CardView dependencies to your app-level build.gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
```